# How can I fix an image within a fancybox popup when scrolling inside the popup?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a gallery with fancybox popup. In the Fancybox Popup I want to show a pictures on the left and some text on the right. If the text is too long, then you should be able to scroll down. In this case, the image on the left should be fixed in the top left corner of the fancybox and only the text should scroll.

I tried versions with `position:fixed` and `background-position:fixed`. However as the fixed-property always is calculated from the viewport, some part of the image is hidden outside fancybox.
Fancybox Version: 2.1.4
Here is my site:
http://tinyurl.com/bl7do5e

How can I fix the image on the left **within** a fancybox popup?

Comment: Example Menu-Link: "talents"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS for the image should have the position set to relative, but the relative tag refers to the position status of the div above it. It should work on these images, but look for this in the future if you are having issues while debugging.

```
.sticker {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
}
```

As for the scrolling text box, you can use

```
div.item-page-contents {
    min-width: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This will give you scroll bars but you will need to mess with the size of the div containing the text to get it to fit properly. Also, if you want the scroll bars to go away, you can wrap the text box div inside of another div that is smaller with overflow: hidden to make them disappear while retaining the scroll wheel.

The renders are cool is this your work?

EDIT: the fancy box has an inline css rule that says that if what you have in the box is too big it will make the whole box (including the picture) scroll, but as long you are careful how you fit the elements in you won't have that problem. Joomla or the fancy box plug-in might also have a way to disable this. I have never used them before so I'm not sure.

```
div.item-page-contents {
    width: 275px;
    float: right;
    height: 350px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I could set the height of the box through jquery. Great idea. So it works fine now! Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean with "renders" the gallery sliding? I did not do it myself. Great freelance work :-).